# add key => value to an associative array in a loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
while($tag = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $arrayresult[$tag['id']][$tag['name']] = $tag['count'];
}
```

the $result contains 4 rows from database table.

i want it to be like:

```
$arrayresult[1]['mac'] = 34

$arrayresult[22]['pc'] = 32

$arrayresult[31]['windows'] = 14

$arrayresult[4]['linux'] = 23
```

the code above doesnt seems to work because it just return ONE element. seems that it saves over the preceding one.

how should i do it?

EDIT: the print_r says

```
Array ( [4] => Array ( [linux] => 23 ) )
```

Comment: What is the query, what does print_r say after the while loop and where does `$tagcount` come from? Should it be `$tag['count'];`? If everything is ok, that should work allright.

Comment: Where does $tagcount come from?

Comment: i typed wrong...but it stil ldoesnt work.

Comment: run the query in phpmyadmin or something like that and see what you get back. it may be working perfectly fine.

Comment: When you need to debug something like this, put print statements inside the loop, and print out the data you're unsure of (like `$tag['id']`). That should tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the query is returning 4 rows? Try `echo mysqli_num_rows($result);`, it should print `4`.

Comment: thx..it helped! i had a while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) inside another while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)). and the latter while loop somehow erased the first $result making it just returning one row!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to know the query before we can really help you but you probably need something like

```
while($tag = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $arrayresult[$tag['id']][$tag['name']]++;
}
```

or

```
while($tag = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $arrayresult[$tag['id']][$tag['name']] = $tag['count'];
}
```

it depends on your query

---

Question was updated...

Test the query in phpmyadmin or something similar. The code could be working fine, maybe you just have the data you suspect.

Also let us see your query.